# Projects in Komodo Edit

Tags: ide, project, edit, komodo, pane

Would anyone here be kind enough to help me with understanding Komodo Edit. Specifically the Project feature and Panes features. 
Is creating a "project" the same as creating a web root folder, meaning a whole site that you can upload to a server in fell swoop or is it something.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Creating a project is simply a way of telling Komodo "these are the files that I'll be working with", you can also set project specific Preferences that will apply to all files in that project (right click the Project in the Places pane and select "Properties").

Some editors/IDE's use the "Workspace" terminology, but it's essentially the same thing.